# How to recover files in LOST.DIR when file type is unknown?

Tags: data-recovery

All solutions I found on google are made for windoz.Ive tried

`file *`   and the results don't say what exactly the file type is.For example is data an application or an image?

`10:     FoxPro FPT, blocks size 0, next free block index 805961728
285218: data
285302: data
369456: PARIX executable
369458: data`

What is PARIX executable and FoxPro FPT? Can the file * command be wrong?

**How to find out what the file extension is (for example .flac for lossless music or .png for picture)**

Comment: [FoxPro](http://en.m.wikipedia.org) is a database for Windows. Also, file looks for magic numbers at the start of a file. Finally, try 'strings file'

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Why is it on my phone? I never heard of foxpro before and i don't use windows.I think the file * command must be wrong...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Did I really know the answer?Why do you say this?

Comment: the file command is saying your files are corrupt. Specifically, that file has garbage at the header. Your question of how to recover it is very difficult to answer, since we don't even know what "it" is.

Answer (score 0):

you can try trID, it is a platform-independent thin app for recovering files in lost.dir folders and other files without extensions. It uses a small database that tries to check unique properties of a file and intelligently guess its extension.

Read the full article on how to use it [here](http://echo.com.ng/2013/howto-recover-files-lost-dir-folder-free/%E2%80%8E)